# Wildcards for matching path

Tags: 7, routes

I am using the [Parsely](https://www.drupal.org/project/parsley) module and I want Parsely to ignore certain paths. I achieve this by setting the paths to be ignored field in parsely's settings page. I am able to use the * wildcard, and I need to know if there are other wildcards I can use to match paths.
Where I can find a list with wildcards used to match paths?

I ended up looking at the function drupal_match_path which is described here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_match_path/7 ; it seems that it only replaces newlines,  and asterisks. Am I wrong? Are these the only "wildcards" available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the short answer is: No, you cannot use other wildcards.

The reason is the use of preg_quote inside drupal_match_path, any regex wildcards you add to your pattern will be escaped.

P.S.: Very cool question, had to take a good look at this.